# Customizing name of localization properties files in hybris

Tags: localization, sap-commerce-cloud

I found this paragraph in hybris documentation:

> Name of the localization properties file follows the pattern:
>   extensionname -locales_ isocode .properties, where isocode is the
>   identifier of a language in the hybris Commerce Suite. For example:
>   core-locales_en.properties or category-locales_de_at.properties.

I noticed that in our company code, we use base_isocode.properties files. How can we customize name of localization properties files?

Answer (score 1):

The names of the localisation files are set in the platform - the code explicitly checks for the name of the extension. E.G.

```
final String locFileName = "/localization/" + extName + "-locales_" + lang.getIsoCode().toLowerCase() + ".properties";
```

I'd argue that this is a case where it's significantly easier to go for convention (and follow the naming convention used in the platform) rather than changing core platform code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what about messages_isocode.properties and base_isocode.properties